# GWT Highcharts - Semi circle donut

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, highcharts

I am using GWT Highcharts and want to create Semi circle donut (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-semi-circle). This is done in javascript with `plotOptions.pie.startAngle` und `plotOptions.pie.endAngle`. There seems to be no method for that in GWT Highcharts. I then tried to set it manually with `.setOption("/plotOptions/pie/endAngle", "90")`, but this had no effect. Maybe this was not support in HighStock 1.2.4 (latest version that is supported by GWT Highcharts)?

My code looks like this:

```
final Chart chart = new Chart()
.setType(Series.Type.PIE)
.setChartTitleText("Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010")
.setPlotBackgroundColor((String) null)
.setPlotBorderWidth(null)

.setPlotShadow(false)
.setOption("/plotOptions/pie/startAngle", "-90")
.setOption("/plotOptions/pie/endAngle", "90")
.setPiePlotOptions(new PiePlotOptions()

    .setAllowPointSelect(true)
    .setCursor(PlotOptions.Cursor.POINTER)
    .setPieDataLabels(new PieDataLabels()
        .setConnectorColor("#000000")
        .setEnabled(true)
        .setColor("#000000")
        .setFormatter(new DataLabelsFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String format(DataLabelsData dataLabelsData) {
                return "<b>" + dataLabelsData.getPointName() + "</b>: " + dataLabelsData.getYAsDouble() + " %";
            }
        })
    )
)
.setLegend(new Legend()
    .setLayout(Legend.Layout.VERTICAL)
    .setAlign(Legend.Align.RIGHT)
    .setVerticalAlign(Legend.VerticalAlign.TOP)
    .setX(-100)
    .setY(100)
    .setFloating(true)
    .setBorderWidth(1)
    .setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF")
    .setShadow(true)
)
.setToolTip(new ToolTip()
    .setFormatter(new ToolTipFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String format(ToolTipData toolTipData) {
            return "<b>" + toolTipData.getPointName() + "</b>: " + toolTipData.getYAsDouble() + " %";
        }
    })
);
```

The working javscript is looking like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 50
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white',
                        textShadow: '0px 1px 2px black'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: -90,
                endAngle: 90,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            innerSize: '50%',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                ['Chrome', 12.8],
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                {
                    name: 'Others',
                    y: 0.7,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Is there any way to get this working with GWT Highcharts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that may be problem with Highcharts version, according to [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.startAngle) - it's supported from 2.3.4. Well, there is no 2.3.4 version, there should be 2.3.5.

Highstock 1.2.4 is version released between Highcharts 2.3.3 and 2.3.5. Is there any chanse you can update Highstock to 1.2.5 ? In 1.2.5 it's supported for sure.